# Recover questions from GameTheory.SE beta?

Tags: discussion

The [GameTheory.SE beta did not live very long](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory) but still generated some questions and answers which might be of interest for our beta.

I was wondering if there is any way to migrate some of these questions back into our beta?

In the past other SE webiste have been salvaging question from the former Econonmics.SE beta right before it was terminated :

- https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/migrating-a-few-questions-from-economics-se
- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/economics-se-is-closing-can-we-salvage-some-of-the-questions

I am afraid it cannot be done from a "dead" SE website, but I thought I might as well ask. Answering the question might require the expertise from a SE-team member, but I am unsure how to get them involved.

I know that one can download the data dump of all activity generated during the beta, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner way of salvaging some question and answers.

Comment: Well and for that sake, if it was to work for former GameTheory.SE beta, we might be able to get something out of former Economics.SE beta too.

Comment: Good idea! I've thought about this as well. It'd be nice to somehow invite those that participated to join this site as well.

Comment: @Ubiquitous or Jason Nichols, should one of us email someone about trying to do this?

Comment: Greetings from the Stack Exchange Overlords! As far as I know, there isn't any precedent for reviving posts from a dead site, but I'm gathering a little more info for you. No definitive answer now, but I wanted to let you know this is getting attention.

Comment: Great, many thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**After a bit of research, importing posts from dead sites isn't a great plan because doing so would mean dropping orphaned content in here.**

There's no guarantee that old posts from Game Theory would fit the style and scope of Economics SE. At the same time, there would be no users connected to the posts, and no one to edit, benefit from rep, or contribute to this community in any way. We rely on users who care about the outcome of their questions to keep this machine running, so I believe this would do more harm than good.

If there are questions from the first Economics beta, or from Game Theory SE which you think would make your site better, best to re-ask them here, from scratch.

Comment: I agree, browse the questions, and if something stirs something, re-ask it in the main.

Comment: Thanks, Ana! Appreciate the follow up!